# List Listener URL

Tags: android

This Code is showing a Toast for each List item, but i want each List item to navigate to a Different URL, 
e.g.  list item one will take me to the google and List item 2 takes me to the Yahoo..
cant find the Code of lines anywhere, please modify it

```
lv.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
            int position, long id) {
          // When clicked, show a toast with the TextView text
          Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), ((TextView) view).getText(),
              Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try something like this.

```
 Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
 Uri u = Uri.parse("http://google.com"); // put your URL here
 i.setData(u);
 startActivity(i);
```

You can get your URL as you are showing in Toast.

Comment: but i am confused that, how list will know for which item is this "google.com" is :s 
like first item in the list is  "Yahoo" and second item is "Google" 
how List will know that, for second item it has to go for "www.google.com" and for first it has to go to "www.Yahoo.com"
please explain a bit.

Comment: Like for each button, we write a different code, here we will write a different code for each LIST item as well ?
like using swtich statement or sumthing like that..

Comment: Adil bro, can i have your skype or sumthing we can chat on, need bit other information as well, just seen your website hooked

Comment: Use BaseAdapter will help you in CustomViews and different actions as well, where you can tag every ListItem. and get your tag iside Listener.

Comment: [This SO Question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1939786/android-listview-different-views-for-every-item) may help you