# Setting up a cutom view within a listActivity item from xml

Tags: android

I have a list activity. I would like each item in the list to consist of a text view and three image views. But all the items line up. How do I configure my xml and/or code correctly?

First, just to make sure things were working, when I wrote my ListActivity I wrote my custom ListAdapter with a getView function which returned only a TextView as follows:

```
public class TA extends ListActivity {

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        class custom_adapter implements ListAdapter {

            public int getCount() {
                return 3;
            }

            public Object getItem(int position) {
                return null;
            }

            public long getItemId(int position) {
                return 0;
            }

            public boolean hasStableIds() {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                return false;
            }


            public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent){
                TextView t2View = new TextView(getApplicationContext());
                t2View.setText("some text");
                return t2View;
            }



            public int getItemViewType(int position) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                return 0;
            }

            public int getViewTypeCount() {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                return 1;
            }

            public boolean isEmpty() {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                return false;
            }

            public boolean areAllItemsEnabled() {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                return false;
            }

            public boolean isEnabled(int position) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                return false;
            }

            public void registerDataSetObserver(DataSetObserver observer) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }

            public void unregisterDataSetObserver(DataSetObserver observer) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }

        }

        this.setListAdapter(new custom_adapter());

    }

    @Override
    protected void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {

    }
}
```

And this worked fine. Then I tried to fill my list with a more complex view

```
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {


            LayoutInflater inflater = getLayoutInflater();
            View layout = inflater.inflate(R.layout.tt_layout, (ViewGroup) findViewById(R.id.tt_root));

            TextView tView = (TextView) layout.findViewById(R.id.tt);

            switch(position){
            case 0:tView.setText("Pos0");break;
            case 1:tView.setText("Pos1");break;
            case 2:tView.setText("Pos2");break;
            case 3:tView.setText("Pos3");break;
            }

            return layout;
        }
```

Using this xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
              android:id="@+id/tt_root"
              android:orientation="horizontal"
              android:layout_width="wrap_content"
              android:layout_height="wrap_content"
              android:padding="10dp"
              android:background="#DAAA"
              android:weightSum="1">
    <TextView android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:id="@+id/tt" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:text="Some text" android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"></TextView>
    <ImageButton  android:id="@+id/button1" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content"></ImageButton>
    <ImageButton android:id="@+id/button2" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content"></ImageButton> 
    <ImageButton android:id="@+id/button3" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_width="wrap_content"></ImageButton>
</LinearLayout>
```

But instead of the correct behavior all of the items stack next to each other and not as seperate list items.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

They will not be separate items in the list.
For this you should do something like this:

```
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

            switch(position){
            case 0: return new TextView();break;
            case 1:return new ImageView();break;
            case 2:return new ImageView();break;
            case 3:return new ImageView();break;
            }

            return layout;
        }
```

I hope you've got the idea.

Comment: your answer works, however the question concerns the inflation of xml layouts not the construction of layouts in code

Comment: Ultimately, this seems to be the best way to fulfill the intent of the question even though it doesn't answer it directly, see the link given in the answer by unluddite below.

Answer (score 0):

You want to use a **vertical** orientation instead of horizontal:

```xml
android:orientation="vertical"
```

Comment: If this change is made then 3 views are stacked vertically in *one* list item, I would like 3 views to be in seperate list items

Comment: See here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1939786/android-listview-different-views-for-every-item

Comment: Thanks, seems hugely more complicated then just constructing the views in code, per bitles answer above.

Comment: You don't have to construct the views programmatically. You can define them in XML and inflate as necessary inside `getView()`.

Comment: Well, that was basically my question, why doesn't my code do that (I tried your suggestion and it did make the views line up vertically, but they were still grouped in one giant list item, they  did not give me seperate items)