# Android - listview contains different header and different layouts

Tags: android, android-layout, android-intent, android-listview

I need to implement listview with multiple headers and list item under each header are different.

For example the first header name is weather, under this header, each list item has city name and current temprature.
The second header name is contact, and the each item under this header contains person name, contact number, call icon, message icon etc.

Can anybody know how to implement this in android?

Thanks
Mindus

Comment: Maybe this is helpful http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1939786/android-listview-different-views-for-every-item

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks guys, Finally i got it with two different listview with separate linearlayouts. And use textview as a header in each linear layout.

Answer (score 2):

In order to achieve Multiple header and different layout in a ListView you should use **Section ListView**

**Section** is like  Header

And you can inflate different layout. Smiler example is given here [Link](http://bartinger.at/listview-with-sectionsseparators/%22Link%22)

[image]

For Complete Source code go through the below link.

http://amitandroid.blogspot.in/2013/05/android-section-listview.html

Comment: @mindus http://bartinger.at/listview-with-sectionsseparators/ this is relevant example.

Comment: but how can i use different layouts

Comment: @mindusI have edited my answer.. I have done from side and posted the complete source code. You will get your desire answer. If so plz accept my answer. Thanks

Comment: It's nice, Thanks for your reply. But i need both section should be scroll-able. In your example i need to scroll weather separately and contacts separately.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know ListView can have multiple headers, but you can't locate them at the postion you want.The all will be located at the top http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/HeaderViewListAdapter.html

I advice you to use separators.Also this can help you https://github.com/commonsguy/cwac-merge
With this `MergeAdapter` you can insert adapters and views in whatever order you want and then present them all as a single adapter to a listview and consequently you can achieve multiple headers simulataion.

Answer (score 0):

you will have to make different layouts for each type of cell (separate for weather and separate for contacts) , you will have to override getView method of list view as well and upon need, just set your desired view for cell to update it.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest not using a straight linear layout for entire sections.

For headers and lists, I would recommend a MergedAdapter, https://github.com/commonsguy/cwac-merge, either that or roll your own.

For multiple cell layout types, this is support in the listviewadapter with the following methods from BaseAdapter

```
getItemViewType(int position)
getViewTypeCount()
```

This allows you to specify how many different types of layout are in use and then recycle the layouts appropriately.